# How to created a load feature during account creation with Meteor

Tags: meteor, loading

I have a Meteor project where there's generally a delay during the sign up process for new users due to slow connection etc.  Is there a way to create a loading screen during this procedure?

I do currently have the `sacha:spin` package which I use with the `iron:router` package when different pages are retrieving data to yield.  Eg. for my home page I display all the users (mainly for debugging purposes) using this code in my routes:

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
  loadingTemplate: 'loading'
});

Router.route('/', {
  name: 'home',
  controller: 'HomeController'
});

HomeController = RouteController.extend({
  template: 'home',
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('users');
  }
});
```

Here's my spinner template (nice and simple):

```
<template name="loading">
  {{> spinner}}
</template>
```

This setup works so nicely, so I was wondering if it would be easy to implement on my create account procedure that I have here:

```
Template.signup.events({
  'submit #signup-form': function(event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var validated = true,
        username = ...,
        email = ...,
        firstName = ...,
        lastName = ...,
        password = ...,

    // Validation

    if (validated) {
      Accounts.createUser({
        username: username,
        email: email,
        password: password,
        profile: {
          firstName: firstName,
          lastName: lastName
        }
      },
      function(err) {
        if (err) {
          // Handle it
        } else {
          Router.go('home');
        }
      });
    return false;
  }
});
```

Can I use my loader that I used for my home template with the create account procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use reactive-var to handle this.
https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-var

Then, in your template code:

```
Template.signup.onCreated( function() {
    Template.instance().isLoading = new ReactiveVar(false);
});

Template.signup.helpers({
    isLoading() {
        return Template.instance().isLoading.get();
    }
});

Template.signup.events({
  'submit #signup-form': function(event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var validated = true,
        username = ...,
        email = ...,
        firstName = ...,
        lastName = ...,
        password = ...,

    // Validation

    if (validated) {
      template.isLoading.set(true);
      Accounts.createUser({
        username: username,
        email: email,
        password: password,
        profile: {
          firstName: firstName,
          lastName: lastName
        }
      },
      function(err) {
        if (err) {
          // Handle it
        } else {
          Router.go('home');
        }
        template.isLoading.set(false);
      });
    return false;
  }
});
```

And in the current signup template you'll need to have the structure:

```
{{#unless isLoading}}
  <!-- YOUR CONTENT GOES HERE -->
{{else}}
  {{> loading}}
{{/unless}}
```

Comment: That worked well, thanks for the detailed solution :)